# php Code to show a text by date is not working

Tags: php, date

I maked this code to show a text by date and time but not working when I add the minutes.
I don´t know what is wrong, any can help me ?

```
<html><center>Look now: <?php 
if((date('N') == 4 && date('G') == 16 && date('i') >= 00) || (date('N') == 4 && date('G') == 16 && date('i') <= 20)) {
    echo "This is the text";
}
?>
</center></html>
```

I would like that show the text

Comment: Try and operator instead of or operator in your comparison. "If this date is greater than this and less than this."

Comment: `date('N') == 4 && date('G') == 16 && (date('i') >= 00 && date('i') <= 20)` is probably easier to read and work with.. What happens with the code and what is the datetime when running? Did you set timezone correctly on server?

Comment: @user3783243 you could even leave off the `>= 00 `as minutes won't be negative

Comment: yes, when I delete the minutes sintaxys, the code work but in this example, not working

Comment: `code`<html><center>Look now: <?php 
if((date('N') == 4 && date('G') == 16 && date('i') == 00) || (date('N') == 4 && date('G') == 16 && date('i') == 20)) {
    echo "This is the text";
}
?>
</center></html> `code`      for exactly time but not working

Comment: Use `DateTime` for working for dates. Much clearer and easier to use.

Comment: I need that the code show a text by specific day and time as Monday, Tuesday... I am not sure that datetime do it.

Comment: First of all you must assign the date to a variable and then test that variable, to avoid that the last test with date() operates on a different time (for example when the first test starts at hh:mm:59:999)

Comment: @RobertoRdguezGlez Can you show an example of a date and time you want to check against? I can show you want the `DateTime` object would look like.

Comment: this code is working at this moment `code` <?php 
if((date('N') == 4 && date('G') <= 16) || (date('N') == 4 && date('G') >= 18)) {
    echo "Text working";
}
?> `code`  when I add minutes, not work :(

Comment: @JohnConde my objetive is show a text "Monday", "Tuesday"... every week at different time... soo, I looking examples and I founded this it

Comment: I re-maked the code: `code` <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Havana');
$currentDate = date('N, H:i');
if(($currentDate >= date('4, 9:24') || $currentDate == date('4, 20:00') ))
 {
    echo "Working by date and time";
 }
?>`code`   --- Thanks all for the suggetions

Comment: @RobertoRdguezGlez, It is not clear at what time ranges do you need to display the text. Please update the question with this information.